# importing mysql query result to json

Tags: php, mysql, json

i am trying to get data from remote mysql database and importing it to json
the connection is ok, the problem is that the result that finally echoed from json is not normal, this is my php code

```
<?php

require("config.inc.php");
$query = "Select * FROM comments";
$res = mysql_query($query);
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

if ($rows) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Post Available!";
    $response["posts"]   = array();
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $post             = array();
        $post["username"] = $row["username"];
        $post["title"]    = $row["title"];
        $post["message"]  = $row["message"];

        //update our repsonse JSON data
        array_push($response["posts"], $post);
    }

    // echoing JSON response
   echo json_encode($response);
```

and this is the result echoed to the page:

```
{"success":1,"message":"Post Available!","posts":[{"username":"1","title":"1","message":"1"},{"username":"r","title":"r","message":"r"},{"username":"t","title":"t","message":"t"},{"username":"t","title":"t","message":"t"}]}
```

while my database table "comments" contain these data:

```
post_id     username    title           message
1           reda        test title 2    test message xxx
2           reda2       title 2         message 2
```

please help
thanks.

Comment: the abnormal thing is the data returned by json,it is not equal to data in the table in the database

Comment: {"success":1,"message":"Post Available!","posts":[{"username":"reda","title":"test title 2","message":"test message xxx"},{"username":"reda2","title":"title 2","message":"message 2"}]} this must be the result instead of the current result

Answer (score 1):

You are only returning 1 row / array by using

```
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
```

So when you do

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
```

you are trying to get a multidimensional array loop, from a single array. That is why each `posts` value is the 1st character from each column from the 1 returned row/array.

You need to build your `$rows` array. Try changing

```
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
```

to

```
$rows = array();
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
  $rows[] = $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not reading your result set from MySQL correctly. You're fetching just the first row and treating that as the entire results set. You need to loop, retrieving each row in turn.

Try this:

```
$query = "Select * FROM comments";
$res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($res)!= 0) {
    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Post Available!";
    $response["posts"]   = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $post             = array();
        $post["username"] = $row["username"];
        $post["title"]    = $row["title"];
        $post["message"]  = $row["message"];

        //update our repsonse JSON data
        array_push($response["posts"], $post);
    }
}
// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
```

Note: I haven't tested this code.

2nd Note - you shouldn't be using `mysql_*()` for new code - it's deprecated. Swicth to `mysqli_*()` or `PDO`.